# How can I load fonts in react before the page gets rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts

I'm using fonts from my Local fonts folder which consists all the files required, I don't want to use Google fonts as that's an extra HTTP request.

Is there any way to load fonts faster before the page starts loading in ReactJS?

The Website's heading is not displayed for a couple of seconds before the font is not loaded yet or some default font is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

This will load your self hosted fonts. Follow this tutorial, to learn more: 
https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project